# Jquery: Adding snap point into draggable object

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

What I want is to add custom points on the dragee object. The default will only snap the border of the dragee object. What I want is to add a custom point in the middle of the object to snap.

For example if the object is squared with width 2 and height 2, then the middle point is 1,1 and will snap to objects (for instance '.snapper') declared in:

`$(object).draggable({ snap: ".snapper"});`

This is currently my work:

```
function MiddlePointSnapping(ui, inst) {
    var dragee = ui.helper[0]; var pos = $(dragee).position(); var mx = pos.left + Math.ceil($(dragee).width() / 2); var my = pos.top + Math.ceil($(dragee).height() / 2);
    var closestX = null; var closestY = null; var dx = null; var dy = null;
    $(dragee).closest('.grid-stack').find(".drag-reference").each(function (i, el) {
        if (i == 0) {
            dx = Math.abs(mx - $(el).position().left); closestX = $(el).position().left;
            dy = Math.abs(my - $(el).position().top); closestY = $(el).position().top;
        }
        else {
            if (dx > Math.abs(mx - $(el).position().left)) {
                dx = Math.abs(mx - $(el).position().left); closestX = $(el).position().left;
            }
            if (dy > Math.abs(my - $(el).position().top)) {
                dy = Math.abs(my - $(el).position().top); closestY = $(el).position().top;
            }
        }
    });
    if (dx < _snapTolerance) {
        ui.position.left = closestX - Math.ceil($(dragee).width() / 2);
    }
    if (dy < _snapTolerance) {
        ui.position.top = closestY - Math.ceil($(dragee).height() / 2);
    }
}
```

I call this function from the `drag:`. The problem with this is when I assign:

```
ui.position.left = closestX - Math.ceil($(dragee).width() / 2);
ui.position.top = closestY - Math.ceil($(dragee).height() / 2);
```

Once it snapped, I cannot move the object anymore because it keeps snapping to the nearest snapper. The code keeps assigning `ui.position.left and top` to snap and will not allow me to move the object.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

This is how I did it:

```
function MiddlePointSnapping(ui) {
    var dragee = ui.helper[0]; 
    var pos = ui.position; 
    var mx = pos.left + Math.ceil($(dragee).width() / 2); 
    var my = pos.top + Math.ceil($(dragee).height() / 2);
    var dx = null; 
    var dy = null; 
    var realdx = null; 
    var realdy = null;
    $(dragee).closest('.grid-stack').find(".drag-reference").each(function (i, el) {
        if (i == 0) {
            realdx = mx - $(el).position().left; dx = Math.abs(realdx);
            realdy = my - $(el).position().top; dy = Math.abs(realdy);
        }
        else {
            if (dx > Math.abs(mx - $(el).position().left)) {
                realdx = mx - $(el).position().left; dx = Math.abs(realdx);
            }
            if (dy > Math.abs(my - $(el).position().top)) {
                realdy = my - $(el).position().top; dy = Math.abs(realdy);
            }
        }
    });
    if (dx < _snapTolerance) {
        ui.position.left -= realdx;
    }
    if (dy < _snapTolerance) {
        ui.position.top -= realdy;
    }
}
```